# React native request failed

Tags: react-native

`TypeError: Network request failed` - I get this error when I try to log in what is the solution to my problem here is the code that I use and thank you

```js
constructor(props)
  {
      super(props)
      this.state={email1:'',password1:''}
  }

  login = () =>
  {
      const {email1}=this.state;
      const {password1}=this.state;

        fetch('http://192.168.1.114',{
          method: 'POST',
          headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'email1',
            password: 'password1'
          })
        })

        .then((response)=>response.json())
          .then((responseJson)=>{
            alert(responseJson)
          })
            .catch((error)=>{
              console.error(error);
            });
```

Comment: please add the error that you get

Comment: First, check your API endpoint using Postman. I think your API endpoint is not valid